# Remote Client Sofware Query bugs

Tags: powershell

I've pieced together this script that queries multiple remote clients and returns installed software names and versions. However, it seems to miss a few programs and I don't know why. Is there a problem with registry entry it queries. Here is my code:

```
Invoke-Command -cn SERVER2012, SERVER2012A -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
        select DisplayName, DisplayVersion | Format-Table –AutoSize 
        } | Out-File (join-path ([environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')) "GetData.txt")
```

Comment: What programs do you miss?

Comment: Is the server 64-bit? If so, you missed the applications in WOW6432Node

Comment: For example, it is currently not displaying: CGTech VERICUT
LiveUpdate (Symantec)
mcAfee Viruscan 
Quest Security Explorer
Treesize pro
VWWare vCenter Update manager
VMWare vSphere

Comment: I defintely missed WOW6432Node. Let me see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that's what I was looking for. Now I gotta figure out how to combine the two (32 & 64) into one script. I'm new at this.

Answer (score 0):

*Don't* *use* the `Format-Table` cmdlet *if you want to use the result later*, so it should work without it:

```
Invoke-Command -cn SERVER2012, SERVER2012A -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
        Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion 
        } | Out-File (join-path ([environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')) "GetData.txt")
```